# Adding additional data to columns of results

Tags: sql

I have a column in my table that is varchar(10) which is basically a date in the format of 2020-10.  I want to be able to have the results show as 2020-10-01 (adding the 01 to the date.)

Comment: Please specify you Database, table, schema etc

Comment: besides not really in line with site rules, this demonstrates a lack of basic research. String concatenation is super easy.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(my_date, '-01')as my_date FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which type of database it is but well, this should work.

As you are manipulating string attribute, you are looking for `CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT CONCAT(my_date_str, '-01') FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Sorry it is a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL:

```
select cast( (yyyymm || '-01') as date)
```

Specific databases might have other methods.